# What is the meaning of phrase "Why on earth"

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, cinema

I was watching a movie "Tangland" and one character says to another:

> "Why on earth I would do that."

Could anyone please tell what is the meaning of this phrase and how I can use it in different scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's similar to the phrase "Why in the world...?"

It's basically asking the question "For what reason, in the entire world (or on the entire earth), would I do that?"

It seems rather like it's addressing a hyperbole or over-exaggerated request. If I told someone to jump off a bridge and they asked "Why on earth would I do that?" they're referring to the audacity or magnitude of my request.

You could use it when you want to reply to someone making a big request (like the one I mentioned above) or imply that their request is audacious (whether or not it actually is; you could use this phrase sarcastically).

Sometimes I use a phrase implying the same meaning: "How on earth...?" I could be asking "How on earth did they get that piano up there?" It still shows that I'm searching for a reason "in all the earth."